# Compactly supported distributions as a projective G-module

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, homological-algebra, locally-convex-spaces

For a Lie group $G$ and a locally convex space $V$ let $\mathcal{E}(G,V)$ be the locally convex space of smooth functions from $G$ to $V$, and accordingly $\mathcal{E}_c^\prime(G,V)$ the space of compactly supported distributions.

A $G$-module $V$ is called differentiable if $v\to (g\to gv)$ defines a continuous map from $V$ to $\mathcal{E}(G,V)$ for all $v\in V$. In particular $g\to gv$ is a smooth map from $G$ to $V$, for each $v\in V$.

Question: is it known that the differentiable $G$-module $\mathcal{E}_c^\prime(G,V)$ is strongly projective (in the category of differentiable G-modules)?

**EDIT**: $\mathcal{E}(G,V)$ is equipped with the locally convex topology from the semi-norms $$\mid f\mid^\alpha_{D,K}=sup_{x\in K}\left\{\mid Df(x)\mid_\alpha, D\in U(\mathfrak{g}), K\subset G\ \mbox{subgroup}\right\},$$
where $\mid.\mid_\alpha$ is the family of seminorms defining the locally convex vector space $V$.

$\mathcal{E}_c^\prime(G,V)$ consists of continuous, linear maps $\mathcal{E}(G,V)\to V$ which vanish on functions supported outside some compact subset of $G$. It is endowed with the compact convergence topology.

Comment: How do you define $\mathcal{E}_c^\prime(G,V)$ ? It is not a trivial matter without problems when $V$ is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: I've edited the question to add information about the topologies on $\mathcal{E}(G,V)$ and its dual. Is there some problem with this definition?

Comment: There is (and neither was) no particular problem concerning the topologies of $\mathcal{E}(G,V)$ . Instead, as I already indicated in my first comment, the problem lies in the definition of $\mathcal{E}_c^\prime(G,V)$ itself. If you define it as consisting of some continuous linear maps $\mathcal{E}(G,V)\to V$ , then there is no reasonable way e.g. to interpret compactly supported continuous functions $G\to V$ as something lying in $\mathcal{E}_c^\prime(G,V)$ . This should be considered as a basic property of something to be called a "distribution" in the "generalized function" sense.

Comment: I don't understand. The notion of a compactly supported distribution (i.e., that it vanishes on the functions supported outside some compact set) is the same als for the classical case (where $V={\mathbb R}$), so what is the problem?

Comment: If the phrase " $\mathcal{E}_c^\prime(G,V)$ consists of continuous, linear maps $\mathcal{E}(G,V)\to V$ which ..." really is what you intend to be *your* definition of $\mathcal{E}_c^\prime(G,V)$ , then I accept it, but then you *should not* misleadingly write " $\mathcal{E}_c^\prime(G,V)$ the space of compactly supported distributions." Think e.g. of the case $G=\mathbb S^1$ where there is no problem associated with the phrase "compactly supported". Take e.g. as $V$ the space of all polynomials $[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ with the topology of uniform convergence. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Given any continuous function $f:\mathbb S^1\to V$ , how do you associate with it an element $T$ in *your* $\mathcal{E}_c^\prime(G,V)$ so that $f\mapsto T$ defines an injective linear map $C(G,V)\to\mathcal{E}_c^\prime(G,V)$ ?

Comment: Okay, your problem seems that functions may not be distributions in this context (right?), so distributions are not generalized functions. In any case what I'm interested in is $\mathcal{E}_c^\prime(G,V)$ and I actually have seen the name "compactly supported distributions" for this but of course I don't insist in this naming.

Comment: Do you remember where you have seen the phrase "compactly supported distributions" as referring to the space defined like you defined your space $\mathcal{E}_c^\prime(G,V)$ which in the case of compact $G$ equals $\mathscr L_c(\mathcal E(G,V),V)$ where thus $V$ is a general locally convex space?